# Is it possible to create a common database class in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, generics, wrapper

We have 3 databases providers we use to connect to our databases: DB2, MS SQL, and Interbase.  I would like to create a single generic database wrapper class that can be used to talk to all three just by passing in the correct connection string, username, password, and the provider desired.

I don't want to have to add references and import all three providers in the database class.  Is this possible?

I have done this before in Java using the `Class.forName()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) built into .NET 2.0 or later, an example of its use would be:

```
Dim factory As System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory
factory = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient")

Dim conn As System.Data.Common.DbConnection = factory.CreateConnection()
conn.ConnectionString = "connectionString"
conn.Open()
```

There are methods on DbProviderFactory like CreateCommand, CreateDataAdapter, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to have references to the individual providers in your application, you will need to handle this a little differently.

There are two main options I see - the first (and easiest) would be to use a dependency injection framework to just plugin the appropriate provider at runtime.  This is simple, clean, and works well.

You could do it yourself without that, though.  Just make a general purpose base class that provides the interface, and, for each provider, make a separate assembly (so the references are separated) that implements this base class.  You can then use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) to create an instance of the appropriate type at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Patrick McDonald's answer, you can store the provider name and connection string in the <connectionStrings> section of your application configuration file.  Then you don't need to have the providers hardcoded in the application:

```
ConnectionStringSettings c = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionName"];
if (c != null)
{
   DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(c.ProviderName);
   IDbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
   connection.ConnectionString = c.ConnectionString;
   ...
}
```

Where your application configuration file contains a connectionStrings section something like:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyConnectionName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use framework 3.5 sp1?

if yes, you should look at Linq to Entity